# What is the fastest way to replace a section of an array with another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm working with [Dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/) and have implemented a reloader which adds higher resolution data as the user zooms into a graph.

In order to keep the original file boundaries, I'm keeping the original data and insert the newly loaded data at the respective zoom interval like so:

```
function spliceAndInject(my_graph_gadget, my_hi_res_data_dict) {
  ...

  for (i = 0, len = current_data_set.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    point = current_data_set[i];
    // NOTE: a point = [time_in_milliseconds, value_for_graph]
    timer = point[0];

    if (timer < lower_bound || timer > higher_bound) {
      new_data_set.push(point);
    } else if (is_injected === undefined) {
      is_injected = true;
      new_data_set = new_data_set.concat(hi_res_data_set);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm wondering whether this could be done any faster, because the graph rendering gets notably slower the more data I'm carrying around.

**Question**:
What is the fastest way to replace a section of an array with another array?

Thanks!

Comment: `ary.slice(0,start).concat(insert, a.slice(start+len))` - this?

Comment: Do you really want to *replace* (and modify the array), or do you want to create a new array?

Comment: @Bergi: either way, I need an updated version with `[old_data][new_data][old_data]` and `new_data` replacing low-resolution `old_data`

Comment: @georg: unfortunately, I have to stick with points being `[time_in_ms, value_for_graph]` (cannot tamper with the server response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the indices beforehand and want to *modify* the array with the data, using the native [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method is probably the best - although for optimized performance you'd need to test against a hand-written solution that manually does the moving.

If you want to create a new array, I'd use this:

```
var len = current_data_set.length,
    new_data_set = new Array(len);
for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
  var point = current_data_set[i];
  if (point[0] < lower_bound)
    new_data_set[i] = point;
  else
    break;
for (var j=i, k=0, l=hi_res_data_set.length; k<l; k++)
  new_data_set[j++] = hi_res_data_set[k];
for (; i<len; i++)
  if (current_data_set[i][0] > higher_bound)
    break;
for (; i<len; i++)
  new_data_set[j++] = current_data_set[i];
```

I think this is faster than yours because

- it doesn't use `concat` which creates a second new array
- it doesn't test all points against `lower_bound` and `higher_bound`
- it doesn't use that odd `is_injected` variable (which should be statically typed as a boolean if at all), whose only purpose is to jump over a loop section

Comment: looks nice! Thanks. Let's try.

Comment: like it. I will try to add a jsperf.

Comment: Ok. Somewhat inconclusive results... see [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/inject-array-into-array)

Comment: Looks like the native array operations (slice, concat) are optimized well in Chrome: see my [updated test case](http://jsperf.com/inject-array-into-array/2). And notice that `j++` is not the same as `j+=1`!